# No matching provisioning profiles found for "... .app"

Tags: xcode, swift, upload

Здраствуйте , не можете пожалуйста помочь , у меня появилась ошибка при отправлении файла игры в itunes connect. Я пробывал заного скачать provisioning profile , но никакого плюса это не дало :( .На фотографии ниже показана ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640727/issue-appsubmit-none-of-valid-provisioning-profiles-allowed-the-specified-entitl

Comment: даже предположу, что в вашем distribution сертификате не указаны beta и in-app-purchases

Comment: Но это не 1.0 версия , а 1.1 , первая уже давно в AppStore . Если бы не была выложена , я бы все заново сделал , весь id сертификаты ...

Comment: а что мешает сделать заново все сертификаты для приложения в appsore?

Comment: Ну щас так и делаю но поч то я не могу создать сертификат именно эти поля dissabled

Comment: Вот я этот вопрос задал здесь с фото-скрином 
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503844/Проблема-с-сертификатом-в-itunes-connect