# Проблема с сертификатом в Itunes connect

Tags: ios, swift, apple

Почему я не могу создать новый сертификат для приложения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит Вы уже создали максимальное количество сертификатов (коих по 3 на `App Development` и `Ad Hoc`). Отзовите один из существующих сертификатов и тогда сможете создать новый.